# how to make my discord bot read if someone is tagged in a message

Tags: python, tags, discord

I want my discord bot to show the stats of someone specific not only the person who typed the command.
My command for the stats is -m stats but now i want people to be able to use command -m stats @“the name of a user“. Would be really nice if someone could help thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.mentions)

[User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.abc.User)

```
for user in message.mentions:
    # get the user's stats
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's info by using the following piec code:

*To get user's name:*

```
let user = message.mentions.members.first().name
```

*To get ID:*

```
let user = message.mentions.members.first().id
```

Then you can check their stats by using your stats command!